# Why my Django admin is not loading with css?

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I have developed a web app in Django and deployed it then I found out that admin page is not loading with CSS. I was gettting the admin page with css in local server but not when I deployed it.
[image: django-admin pic]

Even after using
`python manage.py collectstatic`
It's not loading with css.

Here is my settings.py code

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
```

Here is the static files linkage part:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'first_app/media')
```

I am not able to figure out why it's not linking the css part even after the above code

Django version: 3.1
Python version : 3.8.3

Please could anyone help me out in this
Thank you

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of your developer tools Network tab?

Answer (score 10):

If you are in production you have to run:

`python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

But you also must serve the static files through your web server. The easiest way to do this is with WhiteNoise: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

This will work with Nginx, Heroku, etc. So it's a very flexible solution.

Comment: whitenoise really solve my problem. Amazing solution... I tried lots of things but after whitenoise, everything is perfect. Thanks @PizzaPanther

Comment: whitenoise helped. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

Setup looks fine. You may need to run `collectstatic` in production environment again.

Answer (score 2):

add this code to your setting.py

```
DEBUG = False
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and after running run this command :

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

and deploy project with webservices like nginx or ...

and add staticfiles path to your webservice config
for nginx somethins like this

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/{{your project path }}/static/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't serve static files in production, you are supposed to use other methods for serving your files either with apache2 or nginx. If you are good or know some docker container here is a tutorial that explains how to deploy Django  https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

}
```

Please check also django doc here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Please check this post for apache2 without docker containers https://programmingzen.com/serving-django-static-files-through-apache/

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the solution ,I will try and update you soon

Comment: Does this work for Apache too?Bcoz am deploying it in AWS on Apache

Comment: Yes, check out this post https://programmingzen.com/serving-django-static-files-through-apache/ by ```Antonio Cangiano```

Comment: I did it but still no change, is there any other solution?

Comment: Use nginx and docker now

Comment: Also, if you're using Heroku and it's a test application you can use white-noise, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets 

(but if you have a VPS or a Cloud server everything has been said)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a trick here. After running collectstatic command, you'll get admin statics in staticfiles folder. Just cut it there and paste in static folder and i don't know why Django doesn't support admin static in production. If anyone knows this, welcome for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention that on which server you're trying to deploy your application If you're deploying your application on Heroku then you need to install whitenoise, which I have already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357681/8175084), but if you're using any other server then you can this answer https://www.thecodecity.com/2020/05/django-admin-static-files-not-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staic'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

[Django 3.1 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert this line in `settings.py --> INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
django.contrib.staticfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated, but I spent minutes trying to get this.

If you are in development and using a virtual environment, remember to start your virtual environment.