# STATIC(CSS AND JS) FILES ARE NOT WORKING AFTER UPLOADING WEBSITE ON HEROKU

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-views, django-templates

I have just uploaded my website on heroku, the css and javascript files works perfectly on localhost but doesn't work after deploying. I also made sure to run this command `python manage.py collectstatic` which i did both in the production and development environment but doesn't still solve the problem. I have included the necessary codes that would be useful, i have also included the images of both instances and my project directory

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the image on localhost [image]

This is the image on heroku [image]

And this is the the project directory structure

[image]

Comment: Did heroku run `collectstatic`, check your build logs

Comment: @FalseDev Heroku ran the collectstatic command. i also did that but still same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not serve static file on production and  by default, Heroku does not support this, unless you add whitenoise to your project please follow these steps hopefully it will help you

You can follow the official [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets?fbclid=IwAR16j_4bi-WEMxrA-VwWmFUfPOFP9ef2Kqzb6lM1pVCiKti_dhwoku1ceEg) of Heroku for serving a static file on production.

Comment: Thanks So much, i will check it

Answer (score 1):

```
> Just replace your code with these lines

>urls.py

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0])

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

> settings.py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

> Make sure you run command using heroku cli:
> heroku run python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: for the BASE_DIR that you have specified, would it need the pathlib library

Comment: Heroku's filesystem is not modifiable, `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` won't change a thing

Comment: i tried using the BASE_DIR you specified but got error "path is not defined"

Comment: But when i tried deploying the website the first time i got an error when heroku ran collectstatic command, i had to clean my static files then it worked and i also ran the command successfully

Comment: i have tried your method but still get same result Sir